# Autoincrement that resets every year

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to get to issue a number with this format:
20-1000, 20-1001, 20-1003 ect. where 20 is the current year and I want to reset the counter every year so next year it will be 21-1000, 21-1001, 21-1003 etc.

=IF(TEXT([Created],"mm")="01" & TEXT([Created],"dd")="01"),"1000",auto-increment-number

this is what I have so far I'm testing for the item create date and if if 01/01 I reset the counter to 1000 else I need to continue with the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script to auto filled the value.
Sample code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
var previous= get();
var strings;
        var date = new Date().getUTCDate();
                                var mon = new Date().getUTCMonth();
                                if(date==1&&mon==0){
                                var year=new Date().getUTCFullYear().toString().substring(2,4);
                                                $("input[title='test2']").val(year+"-1000")
                                }else{
                                strings=previous.split("-");
                                var newCount=Number(strings[1])+1;
                                var newValue=strings[0]+"-"+newCount;
                                $("input[title='test2']").val(newValue);
                                }
})




                function get(){
                var previous;
    $.ajax({
                async: false,
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('testa')/items?$select=test2",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        success: function(data){
            var  length=data.d.results.length;
                                                previous=data.d.results[length-1].test2;
        }
    });
                return previous;
}
</script>
```

Tip:you need to change the list title and column name.